# I am unable to loop through full l2 list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to create a function to solve the following problem: Complete the function scramble(str1, str2) that returns true if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise returns false.

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    l1 = list(s1)
    l2 = list(s2)
    l3 = l2
    for i in l2:
        for j in l1:
            if i == j:
                l1.remove(j)
                l3.remove(i)
                break

    if l3 == []:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I am getting a false result while trying random tests.
I don't know why the code isn't looping through the full l2 list.
Please Help.

Comment: The code after `return l3` will never run. Also I don't think this algorithm would satisfy the requirement.

Comment: the code you have given seems to be wrong as nothing after     return l3              will run

Answer (score 0):

Hey when you remove from list much easier is to use delete.
there is no need of l3, you check if the list contains the number
then finding the index then delete.
you return not l2 because if l2 is empty it will return false.
this why using not

Hope that helps!

```
l1 = [1,2,4,5,3]
l2 = [3,4,9,5,3]


for number in l1:
    if l2.__contains__(number):
        index = l2.index(number)
        del l2[index]

return not l2
```

to remove each value all of the time its shows up, simply do it with set sub like this:
set will remove duplicate values. and by using list(s1-s2) you will remove the values which shown up:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
l1
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
list(set(l1))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
l2 = [1, 2, 3]
list(set(l1) - set(l2))
[8, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: after run l2 will be = [9,3]
it will be what left. unless you want to remove the number it self. when it shows up.
from what i understand you wanted to remove only one time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `all` to find that if all of `s1` items are in `s2`, like this:

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    return all([i in s2 for i in s1])
```

some examples:

```
In [26]: scramble([],[])
Out[26]: True

In [27]: scramble([1],[])
Out[27]: False

In [28]: scramble([1],[1])
Out[28]: True

In [29]: scramble([1],[1,2])
Out[29]: True

In [30]: scramble([1,2],[1,2])
Out[30]: True

In [31]: scramble([1,2,3],[1,2])
Out[31]: False

In [32]: scramble([1,2,3],[3,1,2])
Out[32]: True
```